# mysql query to find specific data

Tags: mysql

think a table like this

```
  PRODUCT ID  QTY

(2,6)      2 
(2,7)      0
(3,8)      0
(7,5)      2
(6,5)      2
(8,5)      2
```

i am supposed to find product_attribute which has a value as 2.but it should only display the result as all the product_attributes has a value of 2.

The output should be like this

```
PRODUCT ID   QTY

(7,5)  2
(6,5)  2
(8,5)  2
```

but i am getting a result like

```
PRODUCT ID  QTY

(2,6)  2
(7,5)  2
(6,5)  2
(8,5)  2
```

please help me:(

Comment: Show your query

Comment: Are your ID values really like `(7,5)`? That's not exactly normal.

Comment: So, what's wrong with the result, exactly?

Comment: Why does this row "(2,6)  2" not belong? It has a QTY value of 2, just like the others. I don't understand what you want. Also, you mention fields PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE, but that is not in your example tables.

Comment: Do you have 2 columns or 3?Whats the logic in the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a predicate to the `WHERE` clause in your query:

```
AND `PRODUCT ID` LIKE '%,5)%'
```

That would give the resultset you specified.

But it's entirely unclear why the row with `PRODUCT ID` value of `(2,6)` should be excluded. For example, you could use a predicate like this to exclude that row as well:

```
AND (`PRODUCT ID` IS NULL OR `PRODUCT ID` NOT LIKE '%(2,6)%')
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have another column called `product_attributes` because you reference to that in your post then why not just check the value on that one as well?

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    product_attributes,
    quantity
FROM table
WHERE quantity = 2 AND product_attributes = 2
```

this question is not clear at all as to why you want to filter out the top row.. if you want a correct and detailed answer you need to give a detailed question.